# How should I think about a block-and-tackle configuration weight-lifting machine?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, kinematics, mass, momentum

At my gym, some of the weight machines provide a double mechanical advantage using a [gun tackle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_and_tackle) pulley configuration.

[image: block-and-tackle from Wikipedia]

For a long time when I was using such machines, I convinced myself that if I were to close my eyes, I couldn't tell the difference between lifting in such a configuration and lifting on a "normal" machine (with one pulley and no mechanical advantage).

But then I did the math: as the weight is moving, on a normal machine we have

$$U_1=mgh$$
$$E_1=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

while on a double-mechanical-advantage machine we have

$$U_2=(2m)g(\frac{h}{2})=U_1$$
$$E_2=\frac{1}{2}(2m)(\frac{v}{2})^2 = \frac{E_1}{2}$$

So the potential energy is the same, but the kinetic energy is half that of the normal machine.

That is about the limit of my understanding of mechanics, I never learned about Lagrangian or Hamiltonian mechanics.

Thinking about it from an intuitive standpoint, I might prefer the gun tackle machine because the force I feel is less dependent on velocity, or perhaps there is less inertia to "carry through" certain postural configurations where my muscles might be momentarily weaker.

At the farthest extreme I think we have machines based on long springs or rubber bands, which seem equivalent to the limit of a block-and-tackle systems with higher and higher mechanical advantage.

On the other hand, there is an "assisted pull-up and dip" machine, which seems to do the opposite of block-and-tackle, by increasing my inertia - the static force I exert is smaller, but I'm moving up to twice as much weight.

[image: assisted pull-up and dip from Amazon]

How do exercise physicists talk about these things, or do they? Aside from static weight, what other numbers control the experience I have when pulling on the cable of an exercise machine? Are any of the fancy machine exercises relevant to "normal" movements that we do with our bodies outside of the gym?

Comment: FYI, stretching a spring or flexing a bow or stretching an elastic band are all very different from lifting a stack of plates. The force exerted by gravity on a heavy weight stays the same no matter how high you lift it, but the force exerted by springs/bands/bows will be proportional to how far you stretch or bend them. Of course, a system of cams and/or levers (including your own joints, acting as levers) can alter the force vs. distance profile of any of the above.

Comment: That's why I said "long", I was talking about infinite limits. To understand that analogy, you need to have understood the first part of the question, which calculates the kinetic and potential energy, and you need to understand how it generalizes to block-and-tackle configurations with higher mechanical advantage ($E_n = E_1/n$, so zero in the limit). Maybe I can edit the question to make it clearer, I guess two people have already grossly misunderstood... :)